# Change background color randomly and automatically after 1 second (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I wanted to make an application which changes the background color after 1 second automatically. The below code does give out a random color at the start of the application, but it does not rerun and change color. The error I get is: rgb is not defined
    at :1:1

HERE'S THE CODE:

```
function getRandomColor() { //To give me a new rgb number everytime
return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (255 - 10)) + 10);
}

(function changeColor(){
    let color = `rgb(${getRandomColor()}, ${getRandomColor()}, ${getRandomColor()})`;
    console.log(color);
    setTimeout(document.body.style.background = color, 
        1000);
})()    //used IIFE
```

Comment: you must use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` and notice that first argument is a **function**

Comment: I can't see why you would get that error, is this really all the relevant code? By the way, `document.body.style.background = color` is wrong as the first argument to `setTimeout`, it should be a function: `() => { document.body.style.background = color;} `

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to change each second, not only once right? To change each second you need `setInterval` and pass a function as parameter. Also redefine the color each time.

```js
function getRandomColor() { 
  return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (255 - 10)) + 10);
}

(function changeColor(){
    setInterval( () => {
      let color = `rgb(${getRandomColor()}, ${getRandomColor()}, ${getRandomColor()})`;
      document.body.style.background = color
    }, 1000);
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because of the way you have created the callback, you have created the callback as:

```
document.body.style.background = color
```

This will get executed as soon as JS reads it (that is why you see the color change instantly) and return a value, the return value would be some: `rgb(10, 11, 12)`. When your timer ends, it would try it execute: `rgb(10, 11, 12)`. This throws the error.

Apart from this, you may want to use an Interval instead of Timeout, and calculate new color in each Interval.

```js
function getRandomColor() { //To give me a new rgb number everytime
    return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (255 - 10)) + 10);
}

function getColor() {
  return `rgb(${getRandomColor()}, ${getRandomColor()}, ${getRandomColor()})`;
}

(function changeColor(){
    setInterval((() => document.body.style.background = getColor()), 
        1000);
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to change the background color every second, so instead of **setTimeout** you should use **setInterval**. And the first parameter to the setInterval should be the function as shown below.

```js
function getRandomColor() { //To give me a new rgb number everytime
  let color = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (255 - 10)) + 10);
  return `rgb(${color}, ${color}, ${color})`;
}

(function changeColor() {

  setInterval(() => {
      document.body.style.background = getRandomColor();
    },

    1000);
})() //used IIFE
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want achieve this functionality so you have to do some things step by step

1. create a function which generate rgb and change background number on every call.

2. Place function Inside SetInterval and and set time 1000 for each interval.
Let's do this through an example :

```
function changeColor(){
  var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255); 
  var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255); 
  var c = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255); 
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + a + "," + b + "," + c +")";
}

setInterval(changeColor, 1000);
```

See How easy is that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
<script>
    function changeColor(){
        var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255); 
        var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255); 
        var c = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);              
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + a + "," + b + "," + c +")";
    }

    setInterval(changeColor, 1000);
</script>
```